# Missing filterset object in context using django-tables2 and django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter, django-tables2

I have been trying to create a view with filter-bar and a table of users.
I am using `django-tables2` and `django-filter` libraries and I have this view:

```
class UserListView(SingleTableView, FilterView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'admin/users.html'
    table_class = AdminUserTable
    filterset_class = UserFilter
    paginate_by = 10
```

However the problem is that there is no filterset object in `data-context` sent to template, nor there is no filterset object in self of `UserListView`.
I was trying to replace `SingleTableView, FilterView` to `FilterView, SingleTableView` and then it passes filterset object under `filter` key in context to the template, however in this case when I visit a page with no filter parameters in url it shows empty list. But If I put a `?search=` in url it shows all users and filtering works fine.

Comment: With `SingleTableMixin, FilterView` it is the same situation as with `FilterView, SingleTableView`, no parameters = empty listy

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
def get_table_data(self):
    return self.filterset.qs
```

I don't like it, but it works. I believe that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found in the doc the "strict" attribute:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#strict
but this is valid only for version 1.11.

Change for version 2 is documented in:
https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/788

so adding strict=False to your View should help:

```
class UserListView(SingleTableView, FilterView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'admin/users.html'
    table_class = AdminUserTable
    filterset_class = UserFilter
    paginate_by = 10
    strict=False
```